# PHP OOP website opesource

Tags: php, oop, open-source, web

I'm searching for an opensource php oop website to learn how to structure my first web site. Somebody can help me find that?

Comment: like wordpress, drupal, joomla or cakePHP, Zend, or codeigniter

Answer (score 2):

While i would normally suggest something like codeigniter(or many others) for OOP websites, since you are learning, i would say follow this tutorial. It covers lots of basics, from database connectivity to logins, etc.

http://www.intranetjournal.com/php-cms/

Answer (score 0):

Go with Zend - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html

Comment: Thanks by I'm not searching for a framework. I would like to learn well how a wwbsite is made e built it from 0.